# Use rqt plugins as widgets in a "bigger" GUI

Tags: qt, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to widget-like embed rqt plugins in a "bigger" GUI with robot-specfic parts? The "bigger" GUI might also be a rqt plugin..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190243/use-rqt-plugins-as-widgets-in-a-%22bigger%22-gui/) by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7555 on 2014-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not completely sure if I understand your question.
rqt_plugins are using the rqt_gui API to add widgets to the main window.
You could replicate this API and call the plugins with your own API instance to make them add widgets to your GUI.
But why? Rqt allows for arranging multiple plugin widgets...

---

Originally posted by [Dorian Scholz](https://answers.ros.org/users/485/dorian-scholz/) with karma: 391 on 2014-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0